# How to get a color properties of an element via css?

Tags: javascript

I have selected some elements like

```
a = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass');
```

Now I want to get the background color of each element. I try this

```
a[0].style.backgroundColor
```

it's work fine for me.

But

```
for( var x = 0; x< a.length; x++) {
  var bc = []; 
  bc[x] = a[x].style.backgroundColor;
}
```

It's returning

```
Array(3) [ <2 empty slots>, "rgb(0, 0, 87)" ]
```

I am unable to understand what's wrong in loop.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you go around the loop you **overwrite** `bc` with a new, empty array.

Create that array **once**, before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

you initialize the array inside the loop thats the problem

```
var bc = [];
for( var x = 0; x< a.length; x++) {
  bc.push(a[x].style.backgroundColor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please move the bc variable outside of loop.